# Make a pagination for my table

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, pagination

I've got an ArrayList that come from my database. I pass it to my jsp which initialise a table from it this way :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>title</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listObject}" var="object">
            <tr>
                <td>${object.title}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The problem is that when my list is too long my table become too big so i would like to add some pagination to it. And for comfort i would like to do it in javascript.

I was thinking that i could initialise a variable contaning the list of my  in my script ligne so i could manage them easily in javascript but how can i do that ?

Then i did think about making each line invisible and to put the right one visible when clicking on the page button but i think a better way exist.

Comment: "for comfort i would like to do it in javascript" whose comfort? Yours, or the user's? Because if one day you have to retrieve 100 000 lines just to display 10 of them, the load time and the memory requirement won't feel very comfortable to the user. Also, some people like to disable javascript.

Comment: Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/48dxxm6o/

Comment: Why are you not accepting answers to your other questions, or commenting why they don't work for you?

Comment: Yep i would like to do it in javascript. 
The first reason is that i get my table from a POST method so i'll lose my table if i refresh the page (or it will be complicate to keep it)
Then i think it would be more confortable too to swich the page without any refresh.

Comment: Oh great that is kinda what i was looking for ! Thx Amy.
I was just asking myself i could i initialize the variable "data" with my foreach ?

Comment: Sorry Jaqen H'ghar but i wasn't at work yesterday night, that why i didn't answer it. In my other post you'll see that i always post the answer and thx people for the help